# Uncaught (in promise) when hosting on netlify

Tags: reactjs, netlify, shopify-api

I have this app that loads products from the Shopify API. It works on my localhost but when I host on netlify I get the error.

error:

```
shop:1 Uncaught (in promise) [{…}]0: {message: "access denied", locations: Array(1), path: Array(6)}length: 1__proto__: Array(0)
```

versions

```
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"shopify-buy": "^1.2.0",
```

left: localhost - right: hosted on netlify
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling the `Read product tags` permission (`unauthenticated_read_product_tags`) in the Storefront API permission settings should fix the issue. The tags permission issue is hinted in the error object's path field (`["shop", "products", "edges", 0, "node", "tags"]`). You can check [this](https://github.com/Shopify/js-buy-sdk/issues/597) issue for more information.

Even though the above fix will work, I would recommend using the latest version of [`shopify-buy`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shopify-buy) (v1.2.0 was released 3 years ago) which doesn't require enabling the `Read product tags` permission.